# Flower Identification

Tags: species-identification, flowers

I found a flower along the banks in **north India** ( **near Ganges** ) and I am not able to identify it. According to its leaves I thought it as Prosopis cineraria but I am not sure about it..

**Leaf** - pinnately compound

**Flower**- yellow coloured and
clustered

Other features include **thorns on raches axile**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its ***Vachellia farnesiana***    [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vachellia_farnesiana)

Common name - Sweet Acacia, दुर्गंध खैर durgandh khair (In India)

Comment: Is it also called "Babool" as a common name?

Comment: Yes, "gandh babul". Common names may vary region to region also.

Comment: Can I please know, why my answer was downvoted ?

Comment: Well, I don't know...